# BigQuery rounds decimals to zero when uploading CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I've been trying to upload a csv file from GCS to BigQuery and it keeps rounding the decimals in one column to zero, no matter what I try.

The original data is a csv file and it looks like this when I load it with Pandas:

```
    User    Prob  Date
0   2036312 0.35  2021-08-05
1   2285452 0.02  2021-08-05
2   2285462 0.10  2021-08-05
3   2285472 0.10  2021-08-05
4   2285482 0.10  2021-08-05
```

When I load it on BigQuery it comes out like this:

```
Row  User    Prob   Date    
1    2218472  0.0    2021-08-05
2    2241002  0.0    2021-08-05
3    2243352  0.0    2021-08-05
4    2248842  0.0    2021-08-05
5    2258942  0.0    2021-08-05
```

I tried Auto detect schema and it loads as float, I tried writing schema by hand and passing column as numeric and also as string and I get exactly the same result (all numbers rounded to 0.0).

I'm at a loss! What else can I try and why is this happening?

Comment: when I load on Pandas, data type of that column is float64

Comment: Could it be that the numbers in the csv are formated as a string? In the worst case starting with a space? Could you for a test import that column as a string and investigate that column further by parsing it with a BigQuery?

Comment: How do you load the file in BigQuery? By Code? With the console? What do you do?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I load it with the console

Answer (score 0):

You could try and convert the column to a string in Python Pandas. You theoretically it should detect as string in schema when uploaded into GCP Big Query.